# Reg Ex doesnt validate if i use # along with other characters or number

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

this is the same question i asked before. sorry but i check all the link provided it doesnt help. and sorry this is the first time i asked question here so was not very clear about how to ask

I am explaining here again with full details:

i have an input text field.
I Use jquery to validate the input date entered by user in this input box.

I pass the data enter as parameter in javascript GET method and pass it to PHP and validate it there with simple REG Ex. It does validate in all account. But if i add # with any test case this validation fails. 
 my code:
 Input field:

```
<div id="clntFstName" >
  <label for="clnt_fst_name">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="clnt_fst_name" name="clnt_fst_name" onBlur="checkFieldValid(this.value, this);" value=""/>
            <div class="msgError"></div>
          </div>
```

If you the function **CheckFieldValid** is called as the user leaves a field input box.

java script:

```
function checkFieldValid(value, obj) {
    var elem = obj.name;
    $('#' + elem).parent().children('.msgError').html('');
    var $label = $("label[for='" + obj.id + "']").text();
    var $id = obj.id;


    $.getJSON("ajax/registerClient.php?action=checkInputFieldValid&varField=" + value + "&lab=" + $label + "&id=" + $id, function(json) {

        if (json.status.length > 0) {

            $.each(json.status, function() {
                if (this['fail'] == 'fail') {
                    var info = '<div class="warningMsg"> ' + this['message'] + '</div>';
                    $('#' + elem).parent().children('.msgError').html(info);
                    $('#' + elem).focus();
                    $('#' + elem).val("");
                }
                if (this['success'] == 'success') {

                    $('#' + elem).parent().children('.msgError').html('this is success');
                }
            });
            if (json.status == 'empty') {

                $('#' + elem).parent().children('.msgError').html('this is empty');
            }
        }
    });


}
```

PHP code:

```
if($_GET['action'] == 'checkInputFieldValid'){




    if(!empty($_GET['varField'])){

        // this creates dynamic session variables and add values to it.
        $_SESSION[$_GET['id']] = $_GET['varField'];



        if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/',$_GET['varField'])){

                        $txtVar = 'It is a valid '.$_GET['lab'];
                        array_push($validFieldArray, array('success' => 'success', 'message' => $txtVar));
                        echo json_encode(array('status' => $validFieldArray));
                        $errorJScript = 0;

                }else{
                        $txtVar = 'Enter a valid '.$_GET['lab'];
                        array_push($validFieldArray, array('fail' => 'fail', 'message' => $txtVar));
                        unset($_SESSION[$_GET['id']]);// unset the session variable to clear when page refresh
                        echo json_encode(array('status' => $validFieldArray));
                        $errorJScript = 1;

                }

    }



}
```

I dont know where I am wrong? I did all as told by other members May be I am doing something wrong with Java script when I pass the GET request variables? as far as 
I think I did exactly what other member told me about PHP part. but may be the data is wrong when i take it from Java script part? As i checked it with other values return from PHP. but when I put # in my input box IT does not make the AJAX call and doesnt return the JSON nor set the session variable. So probably when I pass the varible as GET parameter It doesnt run the AJAX and just doesnt validate so plz tell me how can i pass # as GET parameter so that i correctly validate the fields in my PHP .
Plz help I will loos my job :(

Comment: You need to URL-encode the parameter values in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$.getJSON` call should use `encodeURIComponent()` to make sure you're not creating the wrong URL:

```
$.getJSON("ajax/registerClient.php?action=checkInputFieldValid&varField=" +
    encodeURIComponent(value) + 
    "&lab=" + 
    encodeURIComponent($label) + 
    "&id=" + 
    encodeURIComponent($id), function(json) {
```

If you don't do that, then a `#` character will be interpreted as signalling the start of the hash field of the URL, and the rest of the URL will be ignored.

Comment: thanks Pointy. I did that  but it doesnt help. It still doesnt validate. I mean i still doesnt make the Json call to the PHP  as I checked it know. am i missing something else?

Comment: I Tried using urldecode ($_GET['varField'])  for the first uri in php. while comparing it  to Reg Ex. still the same...

Comment: Oh God... It does work now. thanks very much. you saved my day. Thanks very much for the help.